# Commerce Analytics not working

Tags: commerce, google-analytics

On my website we don't get any e-commerce tracking in Google Analytics. Usual analytics works fine. How do I troubleshoot?

Have sold around 200 products since installing & configuring the Google Analytics and Commerce Analytics modules.

The module maintainers haven't replied on the same request on drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/node/2612390

Cheers,

**EDIT**:
I updated from Commerce Analytics from 7.x-1.1 to 7.x-2.0-beta2. Still nothing in Google Analytics, but now ga_push appears in source code.

[image]

Comment: Which method are you using? Client-side or server-side?

Comment: Not sure - how do I check that? I've got the google analytics module with our GA ID in the configuration and the Commerce Analytics added on top.

Comment: Did you set up rules to fire off events? If so, you're using server side.

Comment: I didn't set up any rules, but there's the folowing rule active which I guess comes from the commerce analytics module?  { "commerce_google_analytics_rule_ga" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send google analytics code on checkout completion",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_google_analytics", "commerce_checkout" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_google_analytics_send_order" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ] } }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Any thoughts @nvahalik?

Comment: Do you have a completion page that is custom? Is it including the final bit of JS? If it's customized, then it may not be.

Comment: Just edited the original post and added a screendump. There's some GA stuff in the inspector. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: No, this would be something that explicitly does a `_gaq.push()` or puts some data on the page that has commerce-related information on the page in JavaScript.

Comment: OK, see new screendump above. That's the closest thing I can find...

Comment: Are you using the 1.x or 2.x branch?

Comment: Commerce Analytics Version: 7.x-1.1 + Google Analytics Version: 7.x-2.1

Comment: Should I upgrade to 2.x?

Comment: @nvahalik I just upgraded, and now there's some push-related codes in the inspector (se screenshot in the edited original question). There's still nothing in google analytics from this puchase (made with example payment)

Comment: @Krisoffer Rom, There should be a rule that fires and injects some of the order data into the page. Do you know if that rule is firing? It should be adding some JS into the page that calls the analytics code...

Comment: @nvahalik I can only find the rule already mentioned here in the comments 'Send order to google analytics'. On which page exactly can I check for the code you're talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What method are you using to Push? Configuring the rule, you can select it at the bottom of the edit page:

[image]

I just tried it with Analytics.js support and the checkout page appears to display the Analytics code:

```
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var ga = ga || [];
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {"id":"5","affiliation":"Commerce Kickstart","revenue":16,"currency":"USD","tax":0,"shipping":8,"city":"Austin","region":"Texas","country":"United States"});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {"id":"5","sku":"MG2-YLW-OS","name":"Coffee Mug 2","category":"Product: drinks","price":8,"currency":"USD","quantity":1});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {"id":"5","sku":"shipping","name":"Standard shipping: 3 - 5 business days","category":"Shipping","price":8,"currency":"USD","quantity":1});
ga('ecommerce:send');

//--><!]]>
```

This appears to be correct. One of the difficulties with testing GA for Commerce is that they do not show up in realtime.

So, I'd try it with Analytics.js if you aren't currently using that method and ensure that something like what you see above is being included on the page. If it isn't, then something isn't working on the site side. If it displayed, then check your JS console for errors to see if something else happened. You can also open up the Network tab and ensure that you're seeing the calls to "collect":

[image]

Comment: This worked! Really appreciate the time you've spend my issue here. Hope I'll get serverside working at some point too;)